# Multiple Filter of Dataframe on Spark with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to filter this txt file

```
TotalCost|BirthDate|Gender|TotalChildren|ProductCategoryName
1000||Male|2|Technology
2000|1957-03-06||3|Beauty
3000|1959-03-06|Male||Car
4000|1953-03-06|Male|2|
5000|1957-03-06|Female|3|Beauty
6000|1959-03-06|Male|4|Car
```

I simply want to filter every raw and drop it if a column has a null element.

In my sample dataset there are three of them which are null.

However I am getting and empty datascheme when i run the code. Do I miss something?

This is my code in scala

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object DataFrameFromCSVFile {

  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit= {

   val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
  .master("local[*]")
  .appName("SparkByExample")
  .getOrCreate()

 val filePath="src/main/resources/demodata.txt"

 val df = spark.read.options(Map("inferSchema"->"true","delimiter"->"|","header"->"true")).csv(filePath)

 df.where(!$"Gender".isNull && !$"TotalChildren".isNull).show
 }
}
```

Project is on IntelliJ

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this multiple ways.. Below is one.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object DataFrameFromCSVFile2 {

  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit= {

    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[1]")
      .appName("SparkByExample")
      .getOrCreate()

    val filePath="src/main/resources/demodata.tx"

    val df = spark.read.options(Map("inferSchema"->"true","delimiter"->"|","header"->"true")).csv(filePath)

    val df2 = df.select("Gender", "BirthDate", "TotalCost", "TotalChildren", "ProductCategoryName")
      .filter("Gender is not null")
      .filter("BirthDate is not null")
      .filter("TotalChildren is not null")
      .filter("ProductCategoryName is not null")
    df2.show()

  }
}
```

Output:

```
+------+-------------------+---------+-------------+-------------------+
|Gender|          BirthDate|TotalCost|TotalChildren|ProductCategoryName|
+------+-------------------+---------+-------------+-------------------+
|Female|1957-03-06 00:00:00|     5000|            3|             Beauty|
|  Male|1959-03-06 00:00:00|     6000|            4|                Car|
+------+-------------------+---------+-------------+-------------------+
```

Thanks,
Naveen

Comment: Alternatively you can also try this        df.select("Gender", "BirthDate", "TotalCost", "TotalChildren", "ProductCategoryName")
      .where(df("Gender").isNotNull && df("BirthDate").isNotNull && df("TotalChildren").isNotNull && df("ProductCategoryName").isNotNull ).show()

Answer (score 0):

You can just filter it from the dataframe as below,
    df.where(!$"Gender".isNull && !$"TotalChildren".isNull).show

Comment: Cannot resolve overloaded method 'where'. Should I import something?

Comment: No. Some typo in your code. Please update your modified code.